# Does this mean "Any MIME type"?

Tags: angularjs, http

In the AngularJS docu you can see the following default header added to each request:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, * / *
```

I couldn't find what * / * means but I suppose it means ANY MIME TYPE.
Am I right? Sorry for the dumb question, but I couldn't find it explained anywhere...

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From the HTTP specification:

**"The asterisk * character is used to group media types into ranges, with "*/*" indicating all media types"**

You can read the whole spec [in RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2).

Comment: You're citing an obsolete spec.

Comment: Yes, but http/2 doesn't include any discussion of this and per the http/2 spec: "HTTP's existing semantics remain unchanged."

Comment: I wasn't referring to HTTP/2.

Comment: Ok, but even so, the mime type info the OP asked about is not discussed in RFC 7230, but is in the spec I cited. Additionally: "The interpretation of a header field does not change between minor
   versions of the same major HTTP version, though the default behavior
   of a recipient in the absence of such a field can change.  Unless
   specified otherwise, header fields defined in HTTP/1.1 are defined
   for all versions of HTTP/1.x."

Comment: It is discussed in RFC 7231 (as referenced in my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means all mime types. As you can see at [HTTP 1.1 Standards](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

> The asterisk "*" character is used to group media types into ranges,
>   with "*/*" indicating all media types and "type/*" indicating all
>   subtypes of that type. The media-range MAY include media type
>   parameters that are applicable to that range.

Comment: You're citing an obsolete spec.

Comment: Obsolete? Where did you get that from? HTTP 1.1 is the actual spec for Header Field Definitions, even though there is a new spec it doesn't mean the old is obselete, it's an extension of 1.1. It didn't change until now.

Comment: RFC 2616 has been obsoleted by RFC 7230 and companion specs in June 2014 -- see https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc2616.

Comment: just to clarify; the main issue here is not citing RFC 2616, but stating that `* / *` is valid (which it is not)

Comment: Well, all this discussion is pointless. The citation is part of a spec that is obsoleted by another spec that directly inherits from the old spec that I've cited in my answer. I also realised that i forgot to scape the \*. And also, the original question was about `Accept: */*` meaning that request accept all mime types as response. And also, the proper answer has already been given and acceped as well. Anyways, thank you for your contribution bringing quality for stackoverflow's answers.

Answer (score 3):

`* / *` actually is invalid; whitespace is not allowed here (and it was actually a bug in the angular documentation)

`*/*` however indeed means "any", see RFC 7231, Section 5.3.2 (https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.5.3.2.p.2)